# Windows Azure Autoscaling - Roles defined in hosted service not found in deployment

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, autoscaling, azure-autoscaling-block

I have created a **console application** that has to auto-scale an application hosted in the cloud.
The application has been created using information from [here](http://blog.paulbouwer.com/2012/08/25/autoscaling-azure-with-wasabi-part-3/) and [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/autoscaling/#header-5).

I have no visible errors at run-time, but the application will not autoscale.
I think the problem is this: **`Autoscaling General Warning: 2001 : Roles defined in hosted service with DNS prefix '<app name>' not found in the deployment.`**

I have the output posted [here](http://pastebin.com/nxhFHmWh).

My settings are posted [here](http://pastebin.com/C3fJWxLr).

UPDATE 1:
I have re-run the application today, and the error was gone(weird). The app was still not autoscaling, so I took Fiddler. Every reposnse was ok(200), except for https://mywebapp.table.core.windows.net/Tables('WADPerformanceCountersTable') (404 Not found). Any ideas ?

UPDATE 2:
I found out why I didn't have the WADPerformanceCountersTable. It is because is didn't create and configure the diagnostics.wadcfg file in the cloud project.

Answer (score 1):

Is the roleName in your services configuration correct?  Matches the role name in you ServiceConfiguration.cscfg file?

Comment: I haven't looked in ServiceConfiguration.csfg.  
I took the name from the Azure Management website, just like this(http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/autoscaling/#header-6) guide showed. Is there a chance that they are different? Unfortunately I won't be able to check until Monday, when I get back to work. Anyway, I had to deal with a lot of bugs to get this console application to work, so that wouldn't surprise me that much. Thank you!

Comment: Hello, as I have said in the update above, the error just disappeared. Very weird.